# when I show records from table , sometimes show in records this symbol. I want to understand that why its come sometimes.? i don't want it. �

Tags: php, mysql

this symbol ( � ) show sometime during data shows from table. i have used PHP, MYSQL for my project.

why this symbol come? give me suggestion or hint about this.

thanks in advance..

Comment: check if all places (includes MySQL table, connection, and PHP page & file encoding) are using UTF-8.

Comment: use encoding type for html as `utf8`.

Comment: I think that's typical of sending iso-8859-1 (latin-1) or similarly "8 bit" encoded text data where a web browser expects utf-8.

Comment: this could help you http://blog.salientdigital.com/2009/06/06/special-characters-showing-up-as-a-question-mark-inside-of-a-black-diamond/

Answer (score 0):

usually means you've got a character set mismatch somewhere, and utf-8 data is being displayed in a non-utf context, e.g. iso-8859. ensure that EVERY stage of your pipeline is the same charset, or at least connected with appropriate translation logic:

> browser -> server -> database -> data table -> database -> server -> browser.

any mismatches anywhere and you get mangled text.

Answer (score 0):

specially this comes for `special characters`. so before inserting in DB encode the value. use `htmlspecialchars()` for encoding. and at the time of retreaving decode the text. use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` for decoding.